# Как реализовать таймер с получением подарка?

Tags: javascript, php, таймер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-то знает хороший готовый пример реализации таймера по истечению которого человеку предлагается забрать подарок

Нужен таймер, похожий на этот
[image: Пример таймера]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ку. Годится?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="bg">
  <div class="timer-close">&#215;</div>
  <div data-progress="0">
    <div class="quad quad1"></div>
    <div class="quad quad2"></div>
    <div class="quad quad3"></div>
    <div class="quad quad4"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="timer">
        <span class="timer__top-text">через</span>
        <div class="timer__content">
          <span class="timer-out counter">100</span>
          <span>сек.</span>
        </div>
        <span class="timer__bottom-text">ты получишь подарок</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  ПОДАРОК
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.timer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


.timer-close {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #f1d522;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timer__top-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.timer__content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.timer-out {
  font-size: 42px;
}

.timer__bottom-text {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 130px;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}


div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}

[data-progress] > .quad {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1, .quad4 {
  top: 0;
}

.quad2, .quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1, .quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
}

.quad2, .quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
}


.quad {
  background: white;
}

.bg {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  background-color: #dea2a2;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}
```

es6

```js
const progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
  quad1 = progressbar.querySelector('.quad1'),
  quad2 = progressbar.querySelector('.quad2'),
  quad3 = progressbar.querySelector('.quad3'),
  quad4 = progressbar.querySelector('.quad4'),
  counter = progressbar.querySelector('.counter')
let progress

const incrementProg = () => {
  progress = progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress')
  progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', ++progress)
  counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10)
  setPie(progress)
  if (progress === 100) {
    document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = 'flex'
    clearInterval(progInc)
  }
}
const progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 1000)
const attr = ($el, tf, p, n, n1) => $el.style.transform = tf + '(' + (p || ((progress - (n || 0)) * ((n1 || 90) / 25))) + 'deg)'

const setPie = progress => {
  if (progress <= 25) {
    attr(quad1, 'skew', false, 0, -90)
  } else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
    attr(quad2, 'skewY', false, 25)
  } else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
    attr(quad3, 'skew', false, 50, -90)
  } else if (progress > 75 && progress <= 100) {
    attr(quad4, 'skewY', false, 75)
  }
}

document.querySelector('.timer-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.bg').style.display = 'none'
})
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое